# Regex returning content within multiple square brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using Regex with JavaScript and want to return the content within the square brackets (including the brackets themselves) in the following string:

```
var str = '##abde[fgh]ijk[mn]op';
var brackets = str.match(/\[.{1,}\]/g); //["[fgh]ijk[mn]"]
```

I wanted *`brackets`* to return `["[fgh]", "[mn]"]`, rather than the content `(ijk)` outside of the brackets. How can this be fixed? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that `.` matches *any* character (including square brackets).

You can use a character class like:

```
[^\]]
```

to match any character *except* square brackets.

So this should work for you:

```
str.match(/\[[^\]]{1,}\]/g);
```

Better would be this:

```
str.match(/\[[^\]]+\]/g);
```

It's a little neater since `{1,}` is semantically equivalent to `+`.